# Spring Boot Update

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have spring boot application and i'm working on update request so my enitity is so big and have nested object and classes so how can i update this entity with more professtional way so i dont have to check on every properties if null or empty

I tried to check with if else condtions but it so complex and the code will be so bad

special when I have getLevelOfConsciousness have multi properties to check

```java
boolean changes = false;
        if(update.getLevelOfConsciousness() != null && !update.getLevelOfConsciousness().equals(existsChart.getLevelOfConsciousness())) {
            existsChart.setLevelOfConsciousness(update.getLevelOfConsciousness());
            changes = true;
        }if(update.getOrientation() != null && !update.getOrientation().equals(existsChart.getOrientation())){
            existsChart.setOrientation(update.getOrientation());
            changes = true;
        }if(update.getMentalState() != null && !update.getMentalState().equals(existsChart.getMentalState())){
            existsChart.setMentalState(update.getMentalState());
            changes = true;
        }if(update.getEyes() != null && !update.getEyes().equals(existsChart.getEyes())){
            existsChart.setEyes(update.getEyes());
            changes = true;
        }if(update.getEars() != null && !update.getEars().equals(existsChart.getEars())){
            existsChart.setEars(update.getEars());
            changes = true;
        }if(update.getMouth() != null && !update.getMouth().equals(existsChart.getMouth())){
            existsChart.setMouth(update.getMouth());
            changes = true;
        }if(update.getNose() != null && !update.getNose().equals(existsChart.getNose())){
            existsChart.setNose(update.getNose());
            changes = true;
        }if(update.getHair() != null && !update.getHair().equals(existsChart.getHair())){
            existsChart.setHair(update.getHair());
            changes = true;
        }if(update.getNeck() != null && !update.getNeck().equals(existsChart.getNeck())){
            existsChart.setNeck(update.getNeck());
            changes = true;
        }if(update.getSkin() != null && !update.getSkin().equals(existsChart.getSkin())){
            existsChart.setSkin(update.getSkin());
            changes = true;
        }if(update.getChest() != null && !update.getChest().equals(existsChart.getChest())){
            existsChart.setChest(update.getChest());
            changes = true;
        }if(update.getAbdomen() != null && !update.getAbdomen().equals(existsChart.getAbdomen())){
            existsChart.setAbdomen(update.getAbdomen());
            changes = true;
        }if(update.getUpperExtremities() != null && !update.getUpperExtremities().equals(existsChart.getUpperExtremities())){
            existsChart.setUpperExtremities(update.getUpperExtremities());
            changes = true;
        }if(update.getLowerExtremities() != null && !update.getLowerExtremities().equals(existsChart.getLowerExtremities())){
            existsChart.setLowerExtremities(update.getLowerExtremities());
            changes = true;
        }if(update.getVitalSign() != null && !update.getVitalSign().equals(existsChart.getVitalSign())){
            existsChart.setVitalSign(update.getVitalSign());
            changes = true;
        }if(update.getNote() != null && !update.getNote().equals(existsChart.getNote())){
            existsChart.setNote(update.getNote());
            changes = true;
        }
        if (!changes){
            throw new BadRequestException("No changes found");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Hibernate @DynamicUpdate annotation with the entity. In this case, hibernate will fire an update query only for the field that we want to update.

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    //
}
```

You can check more details about @DynamicUpdate example [here](https://javatute.com/hibernate/hibernate-dynamicupdate-example/).

If you want to get stuck with your approach you might consider using reflection to compare the values.
Here is the sample code.

```
@Transactional
public Student save(Student student) {
    Student createResponse = null;
    createResponse = studentRepository.save(student);
    return createResponse;
}

@Transactional
public Student update(Student student) {

    Optional<Student> response = studentRepository.findById(student.getId());
    Student fromDb = response.get();
    boolean changes = false;
    if (fromDb != null) {

        // Use reflection to get and compare the values of all fields
        Field[] fields = Student.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                Object existingValue = field.get(fromDb);
                Object entityNeedsToUpdate = field.get(student);

                if (!Objects.equals(existingValue, entityNeedsToUpdate)) {
                    field.set(fromDb, entityNeedsToUpdate);
                    changes = true;

                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        if (changes) {
            return studentRepository.save(fromDb);
        }else{
            return student;
        }


    }
    return student;
}
```

Comment: first of all thank you for help. i have tried this before but it not the right way and it will cose so meny issue so asked here to fine another way. thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to check if there were any change between previous object and current object.
You may first convert objects to json and compare.

```
public static boolean compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
    return new Gson().toJson(obj1).equals(new Gson().toJson(obj2));
}
compare(update,existsChart);
```

Or you may use Java Map to check for changes :

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> aMap =  objectMapper.convertValue(update, Map.class);
Map<String, Object> bMap =  objectMapper.convertValue(existsChart, Map.class);

aMap.equals(bMap);
```